# How to use Microsoft Access In your login form for delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access, authentication

OK, so I am a self taught basic coder by watching videos on how to do basic coding with Delphi and i have successfully created an application where i use a text file for a login  form with usernames and passwords being checked (with a lot of help from videos). How can i use Microsoft Access  for the login for the username and a password? I struggle to find a video on how it works. I found a video telling me how to connect ado tables and connections, but i am struggling with the login. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you can follow the video about Ado tables, all you are missing is how to configure the TAdoConnection you use to connect to the database.  Assuming you've got the project set up:

- In the IDE, click your TAdoConnection - usually it would be called AdoConnection1 by default.
- In the Object Inspector, click AdoConnection1's ConnectionString property.
- In the Data Link properties pop-up, select the `MS Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DBProvider` (the version number may be different on your system), then click `Next'.
- On the next tab, in item 1, enter your database's exact name and extension, including the full path to it.
- In item 2, enter the `User name`
- Then click `Test connection`.  Assuming you get `Test connection succeeded`, you're done.

Try that and see how you get on.

Btw, very occasionally you may come across Delphi Ado projects that don't have a TAdoConnection; in that case, you configure the connection of the TAdoDataSet component (e.g. a TAdoTable) by the above method.

If you would prefer to start with a blank form and set it up from scratch yourself, do the following **before** the above steps:

- Place the followinng components on the form: a TAdoConnection; a TAdoTable; a TDataSource (on the `Data Access` tab of the `Component Palette`); a TDBGrid and a TDBNavigator (both on the `Data controls` tab.  Then wire them up as follows:
- In the Object Inspector set the `DataSource` properties of `DBNavigator1` and `DBGrid1` to `DataSource1`
- Set `DataSource1`'s `DataSet` property to `AdoTable1`
- Set `AdoTable1`'s `Connection` property to `AdoConnection1`

Then, configure `AdoConnection1` as detailed above.

Finally

- Set `AdoTable1`'s `TableName` property to the name of a table in your database, thn set its `Active` property to `True`.

Compile and run.

Once you've got it working, set `AdoTable1`'s `Active` property to `False` and instead set it to open in `Form1`'s  `FormCreate` event.  You can also set `AdoConnection1`'s `LoginPrompt` to `False` if you prefer.